# Unable to read attributes of props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I'm building a winery themed shopping app in React and I'm using functional components. I have 12 products (wines) displayed on one page, and I want to make a separate page for each wine when the user clicks on it.

This is how I handled routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/products" element={<Products wines={products}/>} />
    <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
    {wines.map((wine) => (
      <Route key={wine.id} path={`/shop/${wine.id}`} element={<Item item={wine} />}/>
    ))}
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I mapped through all of the wines and created a separate route for each of them, and sent a particular wine as a prop to each "Item" component.

Item component looks like this:

```
const Item = (item) => {
return (
    <>
    <Header />
    <div className="item_container">
        <img className="item_image" alt={item.name} src={item.image} />
        <h1 className="item_name">{item.name}</h1>
        <h3 className="item_price">{item.price}</h3>
    </div>
    <Footer />
    </> 
)
```

When I console log "item" in this component, I get the specific wine and I can see all of its attributes (name, price, image URL), but when I try to access those attributes in order to display them (item.name, item.image, item.price), the console logs "undefined".

How can i fix this?

Comment: You didn't destructure it correctly. Try: `const Item = ({ item }) => ...`

Comment: Oh thank you :) It's a dumb mistake but I'm staring at the code the whole day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've passed a `item` prop to the `Item` component.

```
<Item item={wine} />
```

And then named the props object `item` in the `Item` component.

```
const Item = (item) => { ... }
```

Either rename to `props` and correctly access `props.item.xxx`

```
const Item = (props) => {
  const { item } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="item_container">
        <img className="item_image" alt={item.name} src={item.image} />
        <h1 className="item_name">{item.name}</h1>
        <h3 className="item_price">{item.price}</h3>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </> 
  );
}
```

or destructure `item` directly

```
const Item = ({ item }) => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <div className="item_container">
      <img className="item_image" alt={item.name} src={item.image} />
      <h1 className="item_name">{item.name}</h1>
      <h3 className="item_price">{item.price}</h3>
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </> 
);
```

An optimization I'd suggest is to declare a single route with the wine `id` as a route path param, and then access the `wines` array in `Item`.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/products" element={<Products wines={products}/>} />
    <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
    <Route path="/shop/:wineId" element={<Item />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

...

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Item = () => {
  const { wineId } = useParams();
  const wine = wines.find(wine => wine.id === wineId);

  if (!wine) return <div>No wine found.</div>;

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="item_container">
        <img className="item_image" alt={wine.name} src={wine.image} />
        <h1 className="item_name">{wine.name}</h1>
        <h3 className="item_price">{wine.price}</h3>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </> 
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check null and empty array for "wines" first , if not null then map through "wines"

Comment: If the "wines" were null, I wouldn't be able to send the "wine" as a prop to the Item component, no? My issue is that I can't access the attributes of the prop in the Item component.

Comment: You can pass a `null` value as a prop. That is not the issue here though.

Comment: oh you have to "props.item"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).